# I am trying to filter out uppercase words however there is an "illegal option" error

Tags: regex, unix, grep

the examples are: UNIX, TOMMY, or BUNNY or anything that is all caps.
Here is my code:

```
grep -o "\<[[:upper:]][[:upper:]]*\>" Untitled.txt
```

However this error shows up:
[image]

Comment: It works on my end (Ubuntu 16.04, grep (GNU grep) 2.25). What is the grep version? Did you paste the exact command as the one you used?

Comment: i am new to unix, how to know sir the grep version???

Comment: Type `grep --v`

Comment: here is what i got: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .

Comment: when i typed grep --v

Comment: The screen shot looks like you are using Windows, not Unix.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using grep version 2.4.2 or older. That version does not support `-o`

You are running some very old unix/linux installation or probably some windows machine with [UnxUtils](https://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/) (grep is version 2.4.2)

If you are on a linux/unix installation, you should upgrade your package or base installation.

If on a windows machine, you may use [Grep for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm) instead (which is version 2.5.x) and has the `-o` option

Another option would be to use [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), which is a "linux shell" for windows.

Or, if using windows 10, use [Windows Subsystem for linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)